# Magento success page (1.9.3.9) is showing weird message (Item has been added to your shopping cart)

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento1.9.3, success-message

The code message is shown between 'Your order has been received' and 'Thank you for your purchase'. The template success.phtml looks like this:

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Your order has been received.') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?></h2>
```

Why is this showing this message? What could be going wrong? Where I should look for?

Comment: Somehow your success message during adding to cart was not shown which was stored in magento session now when magento gets <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?> then it shows the message. Try to check why its now shown during adding product to cart.

Comment: This looks logical to me; as soon as I went back to the product page, I saw the message right there appearing; when a product is added to the shopping cart I am redirected to the checkout page, which does not load getMessagesBlock()

Comment: Right. You need to check why its not loading in check if its added.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your template 
1. configuration > Design > "Templates"
2. Then if everything is all right There You should check your Design layout.
3. Check your plugins.